# OpenGL application not picking up 64bit Mesa OpenGL32.dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, dll, mesa

I'm trying to get a 64bit OpenGL application running with MESA compiled in 64 bit.
When compiling both in 32bit it works perfect putting the opengl32.dll and talloc.dll in the same directory as the executable, however, in 64bit the mesa opengl32.dll driver seems to simply pass on the my hardware driver.

If I change the opengl32.dll to any invalid file, the application crashes, which means the file gets read, but passes on to some other driver.

Both of my 32bit and 64bit mesa are compiled in with the same flags, except for changing *-x86* to *-x86_64*.

Anyone happen to have a hunch of what could be the problem?

(btw I'm using Visual Studio)

Answer (score 1):

I can't quite provide an answer, but I can offer an advice.

1. Verify in the visual studio debugger what opengl32.dll gets loaded (the modules tab).
2. Step through an OpenGL call to understand how it gets routed (if you built yourself, you can generate symbols).